# Kasa 3 way switch with 3 black wires

Tags: wiring, installation, smart-switch

I'm trying to install my smart switch in my hallway and keep other one a regular switch

The hallway has two lights and two switches

One light switch has a red, copper and two black wires.
The other switch has red, copper, and 3 black wires.
When I use the app to set up it says I have to many wires.
what should I do with the additional wire, or did I buy the wrong type of switch

This is a picture of the second switch
[image: the wiring connected to one side of the switch]

Comment: The two black wires on top are connected together(electrically).  They can be removed from switch and connected together adding a short black wire, with a wire nut.  The short black wire will then be connected to switch with top brass screw.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome! Would you show a few more photos so we can see how these conductors are paired (meaning, which sets of conductors go into cables together)? That brass-colored screw is one of the "traveler" terminals; it would be very uncommon to have two wires connected there. Seeing more may help us guess why it is done that way.

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the backs of the boxes involved please?

Comment: These are 3-way switches.  Did you know that??  Also, the pictured one is miswired.  Are there any lights that behave weirdly, like only work when the 3-way pair are in certain positions?